# How does one obtain the client's IP address in an AWS Lambda when the data comes from an IoT Core Rule?

Tags: aws-lambda, ip-address, serverless-framework, aws-iot

We want to track the ip of the sender for some MQTT topics.

I see in the Lambda event body or context that the data does not appear available.

Is there an option to enable that I am missing or a work around to get the calling ip at the same time the message is being processed in the Lambda?

Answer (score 2):

In MQTT using AWS I don't think there is a provision to get the IP of the user

> The message broker does not support persistent sessions (connections
>   made with the cleanSession flag set to false. The AWS IoT message
>   broker assumes all sessions are clean sessions and messages are not
>   stored across sessions. If an MQTT client attempts to connect to the
>   AWS IoT message broker with the cleanSession set to false, the client
>   will be disconnected.

You can get more details on this [AWS Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/protocols.html). Also, if they are providing the IP the end user might get exposed.